# Probability of consecutive sixes in a sequence of N dice rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I see that you could calculate this probability through counting the number of sequences of $N$ rolls which contain at least two consecutive sixes and dividing that number by $6^N$, but I'm finding it very difficult to count how many possible sequences of a given length contain consecutive sixes.

Here are my efforts of counting manually/looking for a pattern (letting x={1-6}, y={1-5}):

\begin{align}
&P(1) = 0  &  \\
&P(2) = 1/6^2 & \{66\}\\
&P(3) = (6 + 5)/6^3 &\{66x\}+\{y66\} \\
&P(4) = (6^2 + 2(6\cdot5)/6^4 & \{66xx\}+\{y66x\}+\{xy66\}\\
&P(5) = (6^3 -5^3 + 2(5\cdot6^2 + 5^2\cdot6))/6^5 & \{66xxx\}+\{y66xx\}+\{xy66x\}+\{xyy66\}+\{yxy66\}
\end{align}

Continuing beyond that point it keeps getting harder to tally as the cases start to overlap in more complicated ways and the pattern or formula still isn't so clear to me

Comment: If $a_n$ is the number of sequences of $n$ rolls that *don't* have two consecutive sixes, then $a_n=6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$, $a_1=6$, $a_2=35$. Now there are standard methods for solving constant coefficient homogeneous linear recurrences. Also, the solution is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A001109 with many formulas and links.

Comment: I think that recurrence might not quite work. For example, $a_3$ would be calculated as $35*6 - 6=204$, implying that there are $6^3-204=12$ sequences with consecutive sixes. However by my count there are only 11: {6,6,(1-6)}, and {(1-5),6,6}. Am I off base?

Comment: Right. If the question had been about a six followed immediately by a five, my calculation would have been correct, but it's different for a six followed by a six.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $a_n$ of length-$n$ sequences *without* consecutive sixes satisfies $a_n = 5a_{n-1} + 5a_{n-2}$, with $a_0 =1$ and $a_1 = 6$.

The logic is that such a sequence

- either ends in a $6$, in which case the next-to-last term is one of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and there are $a_{n-2}$ ways to fill in the terms before that,
- or does not end in a $6$, in which case the last term is one of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and there are $a_{n-1}$ ways to fill in the terms before that.

See http://oeis.org/A180033, which has a different (and extremely confusing) description but the same recurrence relation.